# Magento 2 - where is customer registration being handled?

Tags: magento2.2, registration

I created a new field for the registration form.
When a user tries to register, I have to confirm that this new field is filled correctly by the user.

Where can I do that // Where can I find a tutorial?

Thanks!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a Q&A on how to do this for my contact form [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/213102/how-to-change-the-type-of-validation-used-in-fields-on-magento-2-forms-and-where), including validation (from a list of Magento defaults). If this doesn't benefit or help you, [this](http://joshuacurrier.com/development/magento2-overriding-customer-registration-form-template/) resource looks like it covers it and [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184006/how-to-adds-new-fields-on-registration-page-in-magento2) achieves it. Let me know if I've been helpful.